# Find duplicates of dictionary in a list and combine them in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
"ingredients": [
            {
                "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Pound (Lb)", "id": 13},
                "quantity": "1/2",
                "ingredient": {"name": "Balsamic Vinegar", "id": 12},
            },
            {
                "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Pound (Lb)", "id": 13},
                "quantity": "1/2",
                "ingredient": {"name": "Balsamic Vinegar", "id": 12},
            },
            {
                "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Tablespoon", "id": 15},
                "ingredient": {"name": "Basil Leaves", "id": 14},
                "quantity": "3",
            },
        ]
```

I want to be able to find the duplicates of ingredients (by either name or id). If there are duplicates and have the same unit_of_measurement, combine them into one dictionary and add the quantity accordingly. So the above data should return:

```
[
        {
            "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Pound (Lb)", "id": 13},
            "quantity": "1",
            "ingredient": {"name": "Balsamic Vinegar", "id": 12},
        },
        {
            "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Tablespoon", "id": 15},
            "ingredient": {"name": "Basil Leaves", "id": 14},
            "quantity": "3",
        },
    ]
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: is there any code you have tried, that you could share?

Comment: id of ingredient, I'm trying to find duplicates of ingredient in that list

Comment: Try creating a dictionary with the key as the ingredient id and the value as one of the ingredients. As you encounter more and more ingredients with the same id, update the value entry in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a dictionary represented like this:

```py
data = {
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Pound (Lb)", "id": 13},
            "quantity": "1/2",
            "ingredient": {"name": "Balsamic Vinegar", "id": 12},
        },
        {
            "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Pound (Lb)", "id": 13},
            "quantity": "1/2",
            "ingredient": {"name": "Balsamic Vinegar", "id": 12},
        },
        {
            "unit_of_measurement": {"name": "Tablespoon", "id": 15},
            "ingredient": {"name": "Basil Leaves", "id": 14},
            "quantity": "3",
        },
    ]
}
```

What you could do is use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists to group the ingredients by a `(name, id)` grouping key:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

ingredient_groups = defaultdict(list)
for ingredient in data["ingredients"]:
    key = tuple(ingredient["ingredient"].items())
    ingredient_groups[key].append(ingredient)
```

Then you could go through the grouped values of this `defaultdict`, and calculate the sum of the fraction quantities using [`fractions.Fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction). For `unit_of_measurement` and `ingredient`, we could probably just use the first grouped values.

```py
from fractions import Fraction

result = [
    {
        "unit_of_measurement": value[0]["unit_of_measurement"],
        "quantity": str(sum(Fraction(ingredient["quantity"]) for ingredient in value)),
        "ingredient": value[0]["ingredient"],
    }
    for value in ingredient_groups.values()
]
```

Which will then give you this result:

```py
[{'ingredient': {'id': 12, 'name': 'Balsamic Vinegar'},
  'quantity': '1',
  'unit_of_measurement': {'id': 13, 'name': 'Pound (Lb)'}},
 {'ingredient': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Basil Leaves'},
  'quantity': '3',
  'unit_of_measurement': {'id': 15, 'name': 'Tablespoon'}}]
```

You'll probably need to amend the above to account for ingredients with different units or measurements, but this should get you started.

Comment: Python has a lot of hidden gems inside, ``fractions.Fractions`` is nice alternative for eval.

Comment: Thank you @RoadRunner, it's the solution!